# spark ml : how to find feature importance

Tags: scala, apache-spark, feature-selection, apache-spark-ml

I am new to ML and I am building a prediction system using Spark ml. I read that a major part of feature engineering is to find the importance of each feature in doing the required prediction. In my problem, I have three categorical features and two string features. I use the `OneHotEncoding` technique for transforming the categorical features and simple `HashingTF` mechanism to transform the string features. And, then these are input as various stages of the Pipeline, including ml `NaiveBayes` and a `VectorAssembler` (to assemble all the features into a single column), fit and transformed using the training and test data sets respectively.

Everything is good, except, how do I decide the importance of each feature? I know I have only a handful of features now, but I will be adding more soon. The closest thing I came across was the `ChiSqSelector` available with spark ml module, but it seems to only work for categorical features.

Thanks, any leads appreciated!

Comment: You can develop a feature selection based on information gain, namely on the information gain between a feature vector and the label vector. The goal is to select a subset of features that maximize the information gain between them and the label and minimize the information gain among the features themselves. There are several sample codes on GitHub.

Comment: @Umberto can you point me to some of these examples? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

You can see these example:

- The method mentioned in question's comment
  [Information Gain based feature selection in Spark’s MLlib](http://opexanalytics.com/information-gain-based-feature-selection-in-sparks-mllib/)
- This package contains several feature selection methods (also InfoGain):
  [Information Theoretic Feature Selection Framework](https://github.com/sramirez/spark-infotheoretic-feature-selection)

Comment: Thanks, where exactly is InfoGain, here https://github.com/sramirez/spark-infotheoretic-feature-selection/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/feature/InfoThCriterionFactory.scala#L41 I dont find it

Answer (score 2):

Using `ChiSqSelector` is okay, you can simply discretize your continuous features (the `HashingTF` values). One example is provided in: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html, I copy here the part of interest:

```
// Discretize data in 16 equal bins since ChiSqSelector requires categorical features 
// Even though features are doubles, the ChiSqSelector treats each unique value as a category 
 val discretizedData = data.map { lp => 
   LabeledPoint(lp.label, Vectors.dense(lp.features.toArray.map { x => (x / 16).floor })) }
```

Answer (score 1):

L1 regulation is also an option.

You may use L1 to  get the features importance from the coefficients, and decide which features to use for the Bayes training accordingly.

[Example of getting coefficients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235744/how-to-use-l1-penalty-in-pyspark-ml-regression-linearregressionmodel-for-feature/47475058#47475058)

Update:
[Some conditions under which coefficients not work very well](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/109382/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-weights-of-every-featur.html)